# How to remove the selected option on cloned <select> and restore the previous selected option when new option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to clone the `<select>` to another two `<select>` and hide the options which are selected on other `<select>` and show the hidden option when new option has been selected. I also want it to be cross browser compatible.

Here, I have three drop down which show the business categories and all the three drop down have same value. I want to hide and show the options on the drop down base on the options selected on other drop down. For, example If I **select *Arts, crafts, and collectibles* on drop down 1 the it must be hidden on drop down 2 and drop down 3** and when I **select *Baby* on drop down 1 then *Arts, crafts, and collectibles* must be shown and *Baby* must be  hidden on drop down 2 and drop down 3**

```js
categories = [
 {catValue:1, catName: 'Arts, crafts, and collectibles'},
 {catValue:2, catName: 'Baby'},
 {catValue:3, catName: 'Beauty and fragrances'},
 {catValue:4, catName: 'Books and magazines'},
 {catValue:5, catName: 'Business to business'},
 {catValue:6, catName: 'Clothing, accessories, and shoes'},
 {catValue:7, catName: 'Antiques'},
 {catValue:8, catName: 'Art and craft supplies'},
 {catValue:9, catName: 'Art dealers and galleries'},
 {catValue:10, catName: 'Camera and photographic supplies'},
 {catValue:11, catName: 'Digital art'},
 {catValue:12, catName: 'Memorabilia'}
];

var categoriesJson = JSON.stringify(categories);

$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.cat2').hide();
 $('.cat3').hide();

 $.each(JSON.parse(categoriesJson), function (key, value) {
   $("#category1").append($("<option></option>").val(value.catValue).html(value.catName));
  });

 $("#category2").html( $("#category1").html());
 $("#category3").html( $("#category1").html());

 $("#category1").change(function () {
  var cat1Value = $(this).val();
  $('.cat2').show();
  $("#category2 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
  $("#category3 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
    });

    $("#category2").change(function () {
  var cat1Value = $(this).val();
  $('.cat3').show();
  $("#category1 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
  $("#category3 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
    });

    $("#category3").change(function () {
  var cat1Value = $(this).val();
  $("#category2 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
  $("#category1 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cat1">
    <label>Category 1</label>
    <select id="category1" name="businessCategory">
        <option>Select category</option>
    </select>
</div>
    
<div class="cat2">
    <label>Category 2</label>
    <select id="category2">
    </select>
</div>

<div class="cat3">
    <label>Category 3</label>
    <select id="category3">
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function hide() {
  selected = $("select[id^=category]").map(function() {
    if ($(this).find(":selected").val() != "Select category") {
      return $(this).find(":selected").text()
    }
  })
  $("select[id^=category]").each(function() {
    $(this).find("option").show();
    $(this).find('option').filter(function() {
      return $.inArray($.trim($(this).text()), selected) > -1;
    }).hide();
  })
}
```

I've also shorted down your code a bit so its more clean.

**Demo**

```js
categories = [{
    catValue: 1,
    catName: 'Arts, crafts, and collectibles'
  },
  {
    catValue: 2,
    catName: 'Baby'
  },
  {
    catValue: 3,
    catName: 'Beauty and fragrances'
  },
  {
    catValue: 4,
    catName: 'Books and magazines'
  },
  {
    catValue: 5,
    catName: 'Business to business'
  },
  {
    catValue: 6,
    catName: 'Clothing, accessories, and shoes'
  },
  {
    catValue: 7,
    catName: 'Antiques'
  },
  {
    catValue: 8,
    catName: 'Art and craft supplies'
  },
  {
    catValue: 9,
    catName: 'Art dealers and galleries'
  },
  {
    catValue: 10,
    catName: 'Camera and photographic supplies'
  },
  {
    catValue: 11,
    catName: 'Digital art'
  },
  {
    catValue: 12,
    catName: 'Memorabilia'
  }
];

var categoriesJson = JSON.stringify(categories);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cat2').hide();
  $('.cat3').hide();

  $.each(JSON.parse(categoriesJson), function(key, value) {
    $("#category1").append($("<option></option>").val(value.catValue).html(value.catName));
  });

  $("#category2").html($("#category1").html());
  $("#category3").html($("#category1").html());

  $("#category1").change(function() {
    $('.cat2').show();
    hide()
  });

  $("#category2").change(function() {
    $('.cat3').show();
    hide()
  });

  $("#category3").change(function() {
    hide()
  });

  var selected = [];

  function hide() {
    selected = $("select[id^=category]").map(function() {
      if ($(this).find(":selected").val() != "Select category") {
        return $(this).find(":selected").text()
      }
    })
    $("select[id^=category]").each(function() {
      $(this).find("option").show();
      $(this).find('option').filter(function() {
        return $.inArray($.trim($(this).text()), selected) > -1;
      }).hide();
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cat1">
  <label>Category 1</label>
  <select id="category1" name="businessCategory">
        <option>Select category</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="cat2">
  <label>Category 2</label>
  <select id="category2">
    </select>
</div>

<div class="cat3">
  <label>Category 3</label>
  <select id="category3">
    </select>
</div>
```

**Demo2**

```js
categories = [{
    catValue: 1,
    catName: 'Arts, crafts, and collectibles'
  },
  {
    catValue: 2,
    catName: 'Baby'
  },
  {
    catValue: 3,
    catName: 'Beauty and fragrances'
  },
  {
    catValue: 4,
    catName: 'Books and magazines'
  },
  {
    catValue: 5,
    catName: 'Business to business'
  },
  {
    catValue: 6,
    catName: 'Clothing, accessories, and shoes'
  },
  {
    catValue: 7,
    catName: 'Antiques'
  },
  {
    catValue: 8,
    catName: 'Art and craft supplies'
  },
  {
    catValue: 9,
    catName: 'Art dealers and galleries'
  },
  {
    catValue: 10,
    catName: 'Camera and photographic supplies'
  },
  {
    catValue: 11,
    catName: 'Digital art'
  },
  {
    catValue: 12,
    catName: 'Memorabilia'
  }
];

var categoriesJson = JSON.stringify(categories);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cat2').hide();
  $('.cat3').hide();

  $.each(JSON.parse(categoriesJson), function(key, value) {
    $("#category1").append($("<option></option>").val(value.catValue).html(value.catName));
  });

  $("#category2").html($("#category1").html());
  $("#category3").html($("#category1").html());

  $("#category1").change(function() {
    $('.cat2').show();
    hide()
  });

  $("#category2").change(function() {
    $('.cat3').show();
    hide()
  });

  $("#category3").change(function() {
    hide()
  });

  var selected = [];

  function hide() {
    selected = $("select[id^=category]").map(function() {
      if ($(this).find(":selected").val() != "Select category") {
        return $(this).find(":selected").val()
      }
    })
    $("select[id^=category]").each(function() {
      $(this).find("option").show();
      $(this).find('option').filter(function() {
        return $.inArray($.trim($(this).val()), selected) > -1;
      }).hide();
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cat1">
  <label>Category 1</label>
  <select id="category1" name="businessCategory">
        <option>Select category</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="cat2">
  <label>Category 2</label>
  <select id="category2">
    </select>
</div>

<div class="cat3">
  <label>Category 3</label>
  <select id="category3">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @KiranShahi Please be more specific, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean can we hide and show options base on option value instead of option's text?

Comment: @KiranShahi check demo 2

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you for your scenario.

```js
categories = [{
    catValue: 1,
    catName: 'Arts, crafts, and collectibles'
  },
  {
    catValue: 2,
    catName: 'Baby'
  },
  {
    catValue: 3,
    catName: 'Beauty and fragrances'
  },
  {
    catValue: 4,
    catName: 'Books and magazines'
  },
  {
    catValue: 5,
    catName: 'Business to business'
  },
  {
    catValue: 6,
    catName: 'Clothing, accessories, and shoes'
  },
  {
    catValue: 7,
    catName: 'Antiques'
  },
  {
    catValue: 8,
    catName: 'Art and craft supplies'
  },
  {
    catValue: 9,
    catName: 'Art dealers and galleries'
  },
  {
    catValue: 10,
    catName: 'Camera and photographic supplies'
  },
  {
    catValue: 11,
    catName: 'Digital art'
  },
  {
    catValue: 12,
    catName: 'Memorabilia'
  }
];

var categoriesJson = JSON.stringify(categories);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cat2').hide();
  $('.cat3').hide();

  $.each(JSON.parse(categoriesJson), function(key, value) {
    $("#category1").append($("<option></option>").val(value.catValue).html(value.catName));
  });

  $("#category2").html($("#category1").html());
  $("#category3").html($("#category1").html());

  $("#category1").change(function() {
    var cat1Value = $(this).val();
    $('.cat2').show();
    if (cat1Value == $("#category2").val()) {
      $("#category2").val($("#category2 option:first").val());
    }
    if (cat1Value == $("#category3").val()) {
      $("#category3").val($("#category3 option:first").val());
    }
    $("#category2 option").show();
    $("#category3 option").show();
    $("#category2 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
    $("#category3 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
  });

  $("#category2").change(function() {
    $('.cat3').show();
    // var cat1Value = $(this).val();
    // $("#category1 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
    // $("#category3 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
  });

  $("#category3").change(function() {
    // var cat1Value = $(this).val();
    // $("#category2 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
    // $("#category1 option[value=" + cat1Value + "]").hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cat1">
  <label>Category 1</label>
  <select id="category1" name="businessCategory">
        <option>Select category</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="cat2">
  <label>Category 2</label>
  <select id="category2">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="cat3">
  <label>Category 3</label>
  <select id="category3">
    </select>
</div>
```